# A calculation on cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $a$ be an integer such that $a$ is not the $d$-th power of an integer, for $d$ a divisor of $n$, $a>1$ and let $\alpha$ the unique positive real $n-th$ root of $a$.
 Supppose that $(m,n)=d$, for $d$ a divisor of $n$. Let $L$ be

$$L=\prod_{j=1}^{n}(1-\alpha^{m}\zeta_{n}^{jm})$$

I must prove that

$$L=(-1)^n \left(\prod_{k|\frac{n}{d}}\phi_{k}(\alpha^{m/d})\right)^d$$

**My Aproach**

$$L=\prod_{j=1}^{n}(1-\alpha^{m}\zeta_{n}^{jm})$$
$$=\prod_{j=1}^{n}(\zeta_{n}^{jm}-\alpha^{m})$$

We assume $\gcd(m,n)=d$, so $\gcd(m/d,n/d)=1$. Therefore $\zeta_{n}^{m}=\zeta_{n/d}^{m/d}$. It follows that

$$L=(-1)^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{n}(\alpha^{m}-\zeta_{n/d}^{jm/d})$$

and then I can not complete the proof. Does anybody has a hint?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, $\{\zeta_a^{kb},\,t \leq k < t+a\}=\{\zeta_a^k,\, 0 \leq k < a\}$. So $(-1)^nL=\left(\prod_{s=1}^{n/d}{(\alpha^m-\zeta_{n/d}^s)}\right)^d$ and you can probably finish from there.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you

Comment: @Mindlack I still can not complete the proof

Comment: It is probably $\alpha^m$ in the statement you want to prove, else the degree wrt $\alpha$ isn’t right.